# Unity Tile Map. How to add scripts etc to Tile Palette tiles

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Does anyone know how to add scripts etc to the tiles in the tile palette? I want to be able to paint tiles with tags already set and with scripts attached otherwise it is seems pretty much useless.

Comment: I guess its main purpose is to aid level design, in general just some graphics with colliders. If you want to customize the tiles you can have a bit of guide from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_zKWMzJNLY)

Comment: Okay, I can see why scripts may be overkill. However colliders are not much use without tags or layers as that is what is used to tell if a particular object can collide with it or not. Also I can't seem to find how to add colliders to the tiles anyway.

Comment: As I said, tiles are more like environment than interact able objects. Main purpose is to use them as ground/walls etc.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create class derived from TileBase like [RandomTile](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/2d-extras).
2. Instantiate with CreateAssetMenu.
3. Adjust settings.
4. Drag from Project to Palette.